# translate InputStream to String (telnet)

Tags: java, string, stream, inputstream, telnet

[Apache telnet](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html#getInputStream%28%29) uses `InputStream`, which I want to [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) as a String (or String like data).

How can I transform the `InputStream` into something easier (for me) to deal with, a `StringBuffer` or similar.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/309424/262852

Comment: I like:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6938341/262852   because it's easy for me to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

You can consider [IOUtils.toString(is)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html) from [Apache Common IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

```
public static String toString(InputStream input)
                       throws IOException
```

from the doc:

> This method buffers the input internally, so there is no need to use a
>   BufferedInputStream.

Comment: pardon, I meant a **live** stream which does not terminate.  Poor question.

Answer (score 1):

You cant transform the `InputStream` into `StringBuffer`. But if you want to make use of StringBuffer then you can read the input from `InputStream` as a int and append it to `StringBuffer` like below.

```
int i=fis.read(); //it will read Character from stream and returns ascii value of char.
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
sb.append((char)i); //This will cast int into character and append to StringBuffer.
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing it wrong?  this seems to result in an int, number of characters or something, rather than the words I would expect.

Comment: @Thufir yea. fis.read() reads bytes of data and parse into `int`. But you can read multiple character by specifying byte[] in read() method. Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

Comment: this would only print numbers, you wont get any characters. even with byte, you still get numbers.

Comment: you have to cast it into char like this Character ch=(char)i to get character from FileInputStream. Check my answer again, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

This is partway there:

```
package teln;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.SocketException;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

public final class ConnectMUD {

    private static String EOL = "/[#]/";
    private static TelnetClient tc;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
        tc = new TelnetClient();
        tc.connect("some_mud.com", 123);
        readLines(tc.getInputStream());
    }

    private static void readLines(InputStream in) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String read = br.readLine();

        while (read != null) {
            out.println(read);
            sb.append(read);
            read = br.readLine();
            parseLine(read);
        }
    }

    private static void parseLine(String read) {
        login(read);
    }

    private static void login(String read) {
        //hmm, how do you know when you
        //get some funky, non-standard login?
        //look for an EOL of some sort?
    }
}
```

there's a potential for some very large strings there, but I'm just focused on functionality first.  Just trying to start parsing lines for playing da MUD.